# Filtering Data Without sql query

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am developing a pretty big enterprise level data analysis software based on flex-4. I usually need to filter datagrids based on users selection, that requires to run a query on my database. I am wondering if there is any way to filter grid data without sql query? That would take very little time where it's causing me 2-3 minutes delay now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ArrayCollection (or other implementation of ICollectionView), take a look at ICollectionView.filterFunction [property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction). You can set it to what you need after user interaction and call ICollectionView.refresh() - all associated grids should automatically show filtered data then.

Comment: hence those two answers are same and useful too , i thought it would be appropriate to accept them both :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in ActionScript. However, since you use Flex, let's rely on the framework. The feature you are looking for the `filterFunction` (see [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction)):

Given a data object such as `{name:"Jo", type:"employee"}`, you can filter employees with:

```
myArrayCollection.filterFunction = function(data:Object):Boolean {
   return data.type == "employee";
}
myArrayCollection.refresh();
```

Your data grid should then be updated accordingly.

Of course, depending on the number of items being present in your list, this might run in a blink of an eye or be horribly slow =)

Comment: In case this is a AIR application, using SQLLite might be a good option. If not, maybe XML/E4X gould give better performances.